# What is the full story behind the crashed ship in Andor?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, andor

During the first three episodes of the Disney+ episodic release *Andor*, the title character sees a ship crashing during his childhood, and goes on to explore its interior.

What is the background story for this ship, and where in the current canon can this story be found (for example, novelizations, comics, video games)?

Answer (score 2):

So from my understanding is that this ship is a Separatist ship. But beyond that we aren't given any real details about why the ship crashed or what its purpose was. At the moment it's a plot device that hasn't been explored much further.

I believe the best purpose/background right now for the ship is that it was a way to create a very rough timeline of his youth using information a mixture of information that is already known (The Clone Wars and Separatist Movement) and information given in Andor (When he born & Adopted by Maarva)

- Andor is Born in 33 BBY
- Andor is Adopted at Age 9 by Maarva Andor (~24 BBY)
- The Clone Wars Begin 22 BBY

Outside of this, we really do not know much in terms of the background of the ship, the gas onboard, or what happened to the other natives of Kenari (and how this may relate to Andor's past in a Separatist Insurrection Cell on Ferrix or his future travels looking for people).

Comment: I wasn't aware that seperatists used cruisers without droids crews in this Canon.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was Republic's ship.

Comment: @Mithoron It could be that this "Republic Ship" as they call it was nothing more than an early break-away prior to the explosion that is the Clone Wars. We really don't have many details besides the Logo and the usage of "Republic Ship" and the timeline. The Logo fits the Separatist Movement, The Timeline Pre-Dates the Clone Wars so it could be anything from another Org. to a Proto-Separatist Movement and the usage of "Republic Ship" could be accurate, it could be an assumption based off of factors we don't know at this time.

Comment: @AaarghZombies I would assume Non-Droid Crews existed in limited capacity. Seeing as this is 2 Years before the Clone Wars this very much could be some form of Proto-Movement or Early-Form that didn't have the widespread droid usage seen during the War. There are a number of factors unanswered so it could be a number of things and the logo is just coincidence.